# JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.1 - Application Server

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, redhat

We are planning on installing JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.1.  Can anyone confirm whether or not **JBoss Application Server** is bundled with this or not? Also what version of the JBoss Application Server is included?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a second version of the universal installer that additionally contains Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform and installs both JBoss Developer Studio and JBoss EAP.

The version of JBoss EAP is 6.

Note version 9.1 of JBoss Developer Studio is available!